# Ошибка Windows Forms C++ Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c++, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
for (int i = 0; i < L_T_N; i++) {
    word_counter[i] = 0;

    DataGridView ^tmp=nullptr;
    tmp = t_grid[i];
    tmp->RowCount = grid1_RowsCount;
    tmp->ColumnCount = 4;

    tmp->Columns[0]->HeaderCell->Value = "" + (i + 1) * 10;
    tmp->Columns[1]->HeaderCell->Value = type_name[i];
    tmp->Columns[2]->HeaderCell->Value = "Дескрипторный код";
    tmp->Columns[3]->HeaderCell->Value = "Псевдокод";
    tmp->AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode::AutoSizeToAllHeaders);

    tmp->ClearSelection();
}
```

Comment: Что такое `t_grid`? Выу верены что `t_grid[i]` чем-то инициализирован?

Comment: t_grid это массив array <DataGridView^>^ t_grid = gcnew array<DataGridView^>(L_T_N);

Comment: Спасибо разобрал все, да я просто забыл скопировать инициализацию :)

Comment: Посмотрела на дату публикации вопроса, прошел год. Вы случайно не справились с этой ошибкой, просто у меня возникает такая же, а решения найти не могу.